# Scraping Aliexpress site with Python don't Give me Correct Result

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I have problem in scraping aliexpress site.

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-gift-100-Factory-Original-Unlocked-Apple-iphone-4G-8GB-16GB-32GB-Cell-phone-3-5/32691056589.html

This is one url.

What i want to get.

[image]

```
r = requests.get('https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Free-gift-100-Factory-Original-Unlocked-Apple-iphone-4G-8GB-16GB-32GB-Cell-phone-3-5/32691056589.html')
```

beautifulsoup

```
content = soup.find('div', {'id':'j-product-tabbed-pane'})
```

lxml parsing.

```
root = html.fromstring(r.content)
results = root.xpath('//img[@alt="aeProduct.getSubject()"]')
f =  open('result.html', 'w')
f.write(lxml.html.tostring(results[0]))
f.close()
```

This my my code but give me false result.
Inspect on browser has that elements
But above code don't give me anything.

I think requests.get don't give me correct contents. But why and how i can solve this problem. They detect as a bot?. How can help me.
Thank you every one.

Comment: do you want this in only beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 0):

try this
1-use user agent
2-use proxy
3-disable javascript from this site and refresh it then see if the site have this element or it loads by javascript if it loads by javascript
you should find a way to render JS